# Set project as startup in project group

Tags: vb6, projects-and-solutions

I am using microsoft visual basic to create a VB6 application. Application is basically a usercontrol. I have a form in the applicaton.

What i need to do is as we do in Visual Studio 2008 add a new project in the same solution and set the project as a startup project ?

Comment: RTFM: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa232712%28v=vs.60%29.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In VB6 You can have Project Groups (similar to solutions in Visual Studio .NET)

Project Groups contain usually two or more VB6 projects and have the extension .vbg

To create a project group open up one project, Click `File>Add Project` and add a second project. When you click on save you will be prompted to save the Project Group File.

To specify one project as the startup project right click on the project and select `Set as Start Up`

Answer (score 1):

Once you've added the new project, right click on it, an go to properties, where you'll have a form as shown below;

[image]

As you can see in the image, you've got the **Start up** option, where you can just drop it down and choose form to start up.

For setting a *PROJECT* as start up, you can simply Right-click on the corresponding form select **Set as Start Up** from the context menu.
Visual Basic displays the startup project's name in bold type in the Project window.

Comment: The OP wants to know how to set a specific project as the startup project in a project group, not a form in a project

Comment: Yeah, that's what I talked about at the end, I edited to rewrite it clearer.